# Standard deviation on group returns null

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas beginner here. I would like to calculate the standard deviation of `SPEED` for ships that depart on the same date.

I've tried the following and it returns `NaN` - why is that? The correct answer should be `9.9500418759588`

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'LEFT PORT DATE':['21/10/2019','21/10/2019','21/10/2019','20/10/2019'], 'SPEED':[10, 20, 0.10, 50]})

df['RUN STD DEVIATION']  =  df.groupby('LEFT PORT DATE')['SPEED'].std()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because the index after grouping by `'LEFT PORT DATE'` is precisely this column and then when assigning to the original dataframe that has different index returns NaN, you can use transform

```
data['RUN STD DEVIATION']=data.groupby('LEFT PORT DATE')['SPEED'].transform('std')
print(data)
  LEFT PORT DATE  SPEED  RUN STD DEVIATION
0     21/10/2019   10.0           9.950042
1     21/10/2019   20.0           9.950042
2     21/10/2019    0.1           9.950042
3     20/10/2019   50.0                NaN
```

To further elaborate:

`data.groupby('LEFT PORT DATE')['SPEED'].std()` returns a series with index `LEFT PORT DATE`, which is not the same as the index of the actual dataframe. Pandas assignment is `index based` when it comes to series assignment.

```
LEFT PORT DATE
20/10/2019         NaN
21/10/2019    9.950042
Name: SPEED, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you @ansev. Excellent explanation, it makes all sense now.